# not able to deploy on cloud

Tags: go, gcloud

I am not sure why I have this problem I tried to change directories in my cloudbuild.yaml file and my docker file.

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1 ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build af84f8a1-e5f1-4068-868f-75eace6a40b1 completed with status "FAILURE"

````yaml
    options:
       dynamic_substitutions: true

     # availableSecrets:
     #   secretManager:
     #   - versionName: projects/173064054422/secrets/Github_ssh_key/versions/latest
     #     env: '_SSH_KEY'

     steps:

      - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
       args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/indx-engineering-testing/cloudstorage-api', '.']

     # Push the container to Google Artifact registry
       - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
       args: ['push', 'gcr.io/indx-engineering-testing/cloudstorage-api']
  
      # Deploy container to Cloud Run
       - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
        args: ['run', 'deploy', 'cloudstorage-api', 
         '--image=gcr.io/indx-engineering-testing/cloudstorage-api', 
         '--region', 'us-central1', '--platform', 'managed', '--allow-unauthenticated',
         '--service-account', 'moty-cloudstorage-api@indx-engineering-testing.iam.gserviceaccount.com']```



my docker file
````

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.16-alpine

WORKDIR /api

RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN apk add -qU openssh

# add ssh key
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
RUN chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"

# Configure git for private repo
RUN git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/
RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/myprojectname/*


COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./
COPY models/ models/

RUN go build -o /docker-gs-main

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/docker-gs-main" ]
```

Comment: You should see a more detailed error in GCP

Comment: post the entire failure log, this error message doesn't give us any idea on what is happening

Comment: The complete log would be useful to understand the error much better.  Could you please post it?